# Plug-in my backend API to leverage only Gooddata UI Components

Tags: gooddata

Sorry if the question doesn't make much sense, I am just very early on my exploration of gooddata.

From the instructions I understood that in order to use gooddata-ui you need to use the platform to create your project, upload your datasets etc.

Is there any way that I can plugin the gooddata-ui components while using my backend API which implements the needed interfaces?

Can I use my own backend which gives similar responses:

```
{
  "executionResult": {
    "data": [
      [
        "164250"
      ],
      [
        "675250"
      ],
      [
        "328500"
      ],
      [
        "292000"
      ],
      [
        "146000"
      ],
      [
        "328500"
      ],
      [
        "255500"
      ],
      [
        "109500"
      ],
      [
        "73000"
      ],
      [
        "127750"
      ],
      [
        "91250"
      ]
    ],
    "paging": {
      "count": [
        11,
        1
      ],
      "offset": [
        0,
        0
      ],
      "total": [
        11,
        1
      ]
    },
    "headerItems": [
      [
        [
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Alabama",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340109"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "California",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340116"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "California",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340116"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "California",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340116"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "California",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340116"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Florida",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340105"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Florida",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340105"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "New York",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340112"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "New York",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=6340112"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Texas",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=4436534"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Texas",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2210/elements?id=4436534"
            }
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Montgomery",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340107"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "San Jose",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340123"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Hayward",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340119"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Highland Village",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340121"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Daly City",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340114"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Aventura",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340103"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Deerfield Beach",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340117"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "New York",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340112"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Times Square",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340128"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Irving",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340132"
            }
          },
          {
            "attributeHeaderItem": {
              "name": "Dallas",
              "uri": "/gdc/md/xms7ga4tf3g3nzucd8380o2bev8oeknp/obj/2208/elements?id=6340130"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      [
        [
          {
            "measureHeaderItem": {
              "name": "# Checks",
              "order": 0
            }
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I am currently one of the developers working on GoodData.UI.

While the scenario you are suggesting is *technically* possible, it is not something we actively support at this time. The main purpose of GoodData.UI is to allow the users of our platform to create their own custom apps powered by the data from the GoodData platform. This means GoodData.UI is *not* primarily meant to be used as a general purpose charting/visualization library.

Comment: Yeah, technically possible, but the interface is not officially documented for public (also because it may change internally from time to time). I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: Dan and Bugs(!!) I really appreciate you taking the time to reply to my question. I understand that the system was designed with the approach you describe(everything in the same platform) and its not trivial to make the sub-projects independent.
I think it would be very good for adoption if the users had the option to plugin their backend.